# Least dense $k$ subgraph of regular graph

Tags: graph-theory

I consider a $d$ regular graph $G=(V,E)$ and a positive integer $k\in\{1,...,|V|\}$. I am looking for the least dense vertex induced sub-graph $G_k=(V_k,E_k)$ of $G$ on $k$ vertices, i.e., the sub-graph which satisfies $|E_k|=\min_{U\subset V,|U|=k}|\{\langle u,v\rangle\in | u,v\in U\}|$.

For densest sub-graphs (exchange the $\min$ with a $\max$) there are plenty of publications, about the difficulty to find them and so on. But I am unable to find anythin about least dense sub-graphs. Is this not interesting or am I using an incorrect name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By complementing the graph you turn the "minimum" version into a "maximum" version and vice versa, so the two problems are equivalent (note that regularity is preserved).